# Hardware Recommendation to Wirelessly measure Cat Wheel Revolutions

Tags: wifi

I'd like to attach a battery powered IOT Device to my Cat Wheel to measure the number of times it rotates across the afternoon.  Not too concerned about what programming language is involved in writing the code for it. It has a nice surface on the wheel to mount a magnet and on the supporting leg to catch a signal from it passing if there is a nice way to measure that.  You can see the cat wheel at https://www.ziggydoo.com/en/home/8-ferris-cat-exercise-wheel.html#/11-color-black

Any ideas are greatly appreciated for this very important project
Patrick

Comment: Please use the https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for this sort of question.

Comment: Also you've not said what you want to do with this information, so it's impossible to suggest something. Just counting pulses either with a hall probe/reed switch is possible with a PIC, but then how that data is represented/stored is left blank.

Comment: Lol are we discussing a $500 kitty exercise wheel? Does the cat even use it? Or is that why you want to count the revolutions?

Answer (score 3):

Its not very complex, you could use some thing as simple as an infra red led powered by a battery that is stuck on the wheel and a IR receiver somewhere close by such that the receiver generates a pulse every time it receives the light from the led. You can use this pulse to increment a counter. and as soon as the counter is incremented, send the data to the destination (server) via your IoT device. IR is just one of the many options you might find. Just search for proximity sensors. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like an ESP8266 with a hall sensor and a magnet. You could then view the revisions online by running a small server on the ESP.